# Error importing underscore typescript @types file

Tags: typescript, underscore.js, gulp-typescript

I added the package *@types/underscore* in an application, and updated the ts package to the *2.4.2* version, but if I try to compile I receive the error messages:

```
node_modules\@types\underscore\index.d.ts(8,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules\@types\underscore\index.d.ts(8,11): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules\@types\underscore\index.d.ts(8,22): error TS1005: '{' expected.
```

corresponding to

```
export as namespace _;
```

These are the ts parameters:

```
.pipe(tsc({
    target: 'ES6',
    declarationFiles: false,
    noExternalResolve: true,

    inlineSources: true,
    inlineSourceMap: true,
    types: [ "underscore", "cordova-plugin-camera" ]
}))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've been unable to recreate the error that you're experiencing. How are you installing the underscore types? I.e. Are you using `npm install @types/underscore` to do that? How are you building the TypeScript? I.e. Are you using gulp-typescript, for instance? Have you tried building the TypeScript from the command line using the TypeScript `tsc` compiler directly?

Comment: looks like the problem was I have to update gulp-typescript too. Now I don't have anymore this error

Comment: same error here but in my tougth the problem stored in node_modules folder. i have tried to get my project to start it gives same error as above. but i copy paste some one who s project is working it works fine. git ignore file ignores node_modules folder. Sorry for my poor writing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `gulp-typescript` is out of date. We can update it like this:

```
npm update gulp-typescript --save-dev
```